# Pre-processing irregular, high frequency time-series data in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, bigdata, pandas

...posted originally in StackOverflow (might be better suited here)

- **Small Picture:**

I am working on pre-processing irregular, high frequency time-series data. In one second, I can have multiple data points, as seen below in the `timestamp` field:

```
"timestamp": "2018-06-03T12:27:54.253" 
"timestamp": "2018-06-03T12:27:54.409"
"timestamp": "2018-06-03T12:27:54.548"
```

I'm in the process of developing a sampling scheme for this time-series data so that I can reduce the number of data points, and standardize time steps without losing information or introducing any bias.

So far I've been using Pandas `pd.resample()` on just a small subset of our data (5 days ~ 2 million records) by using `mean` as the aggregation function and linear interpolation. I am on downsampling the data by seconds, minutes, and hours for experimental purposes which takes care of the irregular time steps of the original data.

- **Larger Picture:**

I am working with many millions of records (data from April - today) that have been queried from elasticsearch and, ideally, want to pre-process/sample within this large pool of time series data to only obtain statistically significant data points. The purpose of this pre-processing step is for future data exploration/modeling.

- **Question:**

How can I modify my current pre-processing scheme to ensure optimal processing for Millions of records and still maintain their statistical properties (no bias introduced)?

I'm aware that there is possibly a better way to approach the processing this kind of data. Any input is greatly appreciated...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, downsampling is always **lossy**. I will give you **two** hints.

1. [Nyquist-Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) Theorem. What it says in short is that **the max frequency that you may observe in a sampled signal is half of the sampling frequency**. This means that if you downsample the data every 1 hour, you can observe dynamic phenomena with period of 2 hours (or more). Another way of looking at the theorem is **"you have to sample the signal at least twice as fast as the maximum frequency that you expect to see in it"**.

   Engineering rule of thumb: Sample the signal **at least 10 times** faster than the expected highest frequency, not just 2 times.
2. **Histogram Representation**. Since you have a huge database, it might make sense to convert your variables into histograms! In this way, you will greatly reduce their size. You discretize every real-valued variable into bins and then instead of storing the exact value of the variable you just increase the count of the appropriate bin by 1. There are a lot of Machine Learning algorithms that deal with histogram representations, such as this:

   https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b8c8/347f9c33935b97703ecd35a67af5c5508487.pdf

Hope it helps :) !